# I want my script to echo "$1" into a file literally

Tags: bash, variables, echo

This is part of my script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "ls /SomeFolder | grep $1 | xargs cat | grep something | grep  .txt | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/;$//';" >> script2.sh
```

This echos everything nicely into my script except $1 and $2. Instead of that it outputs the input of those variables but i want it to literally read "$1" and "$2". Help?

Answer (score 4):

Escape it:

```
echo "ls /SomeFolder | grep \$1 | xargs cat | grep something | grep  .txt | awk '{print \$2}' | sed 's/;\$//';" >> script2.sh
```

Quote it:

```
echo "ls /SomeFolder | grep "'$'"1 | xargs cat | grep something | grep  .txt | awk '{print "'$'"2}' | sed 's/;"'$'"//';" >> script2.sh
```

or like this:

```
echo 'ls /SomeFolder | grep $1 | xargs cat | grep something | grep  .txt | awk '\''{print $2}'\'' | sed '\''s/;$//'\'';' >> script2.sh
```

Use [quoted here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents):

```
cat << 'EOF' >> script2.sh
ls /SomeFolder | grep $1 | xargs cat | grep something | grep  .txt | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/;$//';
EOF
```

Basically you want to prevent expansion, ie. take the string literaly. You may want to read [bashfaq quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd never write this (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html and you don't need greps+seds+pipes when you're using awk):

```
ls /SomeFolder | grep $1 | xargs cat | grep something | grep  .txt | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/;$//'`
```

you'd write this instead:

```
find /SomeFolder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*$1*" -exec \
    awk '/something/ && /.txt/{sub(/;$/,"",$2); print $2}' {} +
```

or if you prefer using `print | xargs` instead of `-exec`:

```
find /SomeFolder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*$1*" -print0 |
    xargs -0 awk '/something/ && /.txt/{sub(/;$/,"",$2); print $2}'
```

and now to append that script to a file would be:

```
cat <<'EOF' >> script2.sh
find /SomeFolder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*$1*" -print0 |
    xargs -0 awk '/something/ && /.txt/{sub(/;$/,"",$2); print $2}'
EOF
```

Btw, if you want the `.` in `.txt` to be treated literally instead of as a regexp metachar meaning "any character" then you should be using  `\.txt` instead of `.txt`.